# null reference exception error for my windows form app

Tags: winforms

I have a Setting.cs file containing the info

```
[Serializable]
public class Setting
{
    public Setting()     {}

    public String defaultAlertTone = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\Sounds\\applause-2.wav";        
}
```

and my settingsForm retrieving the info through this code

```
Setting settingObject;
public SoundPlayer player;

public settingsForm(backgroundForm backgroundFormObject)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.backgroundFormObject = backgroundFormObject;
    settingObject = backgroundFormObject.getSetting();
}

private void InitializeSound()
{
    // Create an instance of the SoundPlayer class.
    player = new SoundPlayer();
    player.SoundLocation = settingObject.defaultAlertTone;

    // Listen for the LoadCompleted event.
    player.LoadCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(player_LoadCompleted);

    // Listen for the SoundLocationChanged event.
    player.SoundLocationChanged += new EventHandler(player_LocationChanged);
}
```

Why is it that every time I run the app, there would be a null reference exception on the

```
player.SoundLocation = settingObject.defaultAlertTone;
```

the `backgroundFormObject.getSetting();` is just a method to retrieve the setting object. the code for it are as follows

```
Setting settingObj = new Setting();

public Setting getSetting()
    {
        return settingObj;
    }
```

Comment: We need to see the code for backgroundFormObject.getSetting() as that is where your error appears to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons could be

1. `InitializeSound()` is somehow running before `settingsForm` (not likely, but this would make the `settingObject` not initialized and refer to `null`).
2. If this is the complete code for `Setting` class, i don't see how calling `new Setting()` anywhere would make a difference. So use `Setting settingObject = new Setting();` when you first define this property in the `settingsForm` class.
3. It is not the `settingObject` which is null.

Comment: If I do that I would be erasing my previous settings?

Comment: My bad. Is that your whole settings class code? Anyway, your `backgroundFormObject.getSetting();` is probably returning `null`. As in @Skuld's comment, can we see the code for that?